# How do I apply a subschema to an value when the key is unknown with JSON Schema?

Tags: python, json, data-structures, jsonschema

Got a bit of a puzzle here, I'm trying to build a schema to use in my python app, But I can't figure out how to get this "we" field to be both required and contain a random string (ex: "QWERT1")

```
{
  "we": [
    {
      "finished": "01.23.2020 12:56:31",
      "run": "02611",
      "scenarios": [
        {
          "name": "name",
          "status": "failed",
          "run_id": "42",
          "tests": [
            {
              "test_id": "7",
              "name": "TC29",
              "status": "success",
              "finished": "01.23.2020 12:56:31"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Rest of the fields should be also mandatory (name, status etc). If I exclude the "we" from the required the rest of the fields are treated as non-mandatory, and if I add the "we" as mandatory I can't then use there any other word :/
This my schema I've ended up with (with "we" mandatory):

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "we": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "finished": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "run": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "scenarios": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": [
                {
                  "type": "object",
                  "properties": {
                    "name": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "status": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "run_id": {
                      "type": "string"
                    },
                    "tests": {
                      "type": "array",
                      "items": [
                        {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties": {
                            "test_id": {
                              "type": "string"
                            },
                            "name": {
                              "type": "string"
                            },
                            "status": {
                              "type": "string"
                            },
                            "finished": {
                              "type": "string"
                            }
                          },
                          "required": [
                            "test_id",
                            "name",
                            "status",
                            "finished"
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  "required": [
                    "name",
                    "status",
                    "run_id",
                    "tests"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "finished",
            "run",
            "scenarios"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "we"
  ]
}
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: This is simpler to build if you use draft-7 JSON Schema. Is there any reason you have to use draft-4?

Comment: No, not at all it can be draft7

Comment: You have shown the `we` field is an array. What do you mean by "contain a random string"? `we` cannot be both an array and a string.

Can you please provide examples of data you want to pass and data you want to fail validation, and explain why for each?

Comment: Sure, sorry if being unclear - I do understand it can be one or another what I mean I want this array object name to be a random string not a fixed one as I got now ("we") and for example this array could be named "qwert1" or anything else and this array should also be marked still as `required`

Comment: So `we` could actually be anything? OK.

Comment: exactly, but still it contents should be as required ("status", "scenarios" etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the root object key could be any string.

First, you need to replace `required` with `minProperties: 1`. If you require only 1 property, you also need `maxProperties: 1`.

Next, you need to use `additionalProperties` rather than `properties > we`.

`additionalProperties` applies the value subschema to all property values at the JSON instance location object.

Here's a bare version of that schema...

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "minProperties": 1,
  "additionalProperties": {}
}
```

You can test it with your schema and instance here: https://jsonschema.dev/s/2kE9y